# String output twice when calling printf from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

When calling printf to display a status message to the console, it outputs twice. Not sure why. I'd expect my output to be:

```
Generating move list file...
Done
```

But instead I get:

```
Generating move list file...
Done
Done
```

I get a duplicate "Done" for some reason.

```
[SECTION .data]
GenMsg:     db "Generating move list file...",10
DoneMsg:    db "Done",10

extern printf

[SECTION .bss]

[SECTION .text]
global main

main:
push ebp            ; set up stack frame
mov ebp,esp
push ebx            ; save regs
push esi
push edi

push GenMsg         ; push addr of gen msg on stack
call printf         ; display gen msg
add esp,4           ; clean up stack 1 parm * 4 = 4 bytes

push DoneMsg        ; push addr of done msg on stack
call printf         ; display done msg
add esp,4           ; clean up stack 1 parm * 4 = 4 bytes

exit:
pop edi             ; restore regs
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp,ebp         ; destroy stack frame
pop ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your strings aren't properly [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). So what happens when you print `GenMsg` is that both of your strings get printed. Then you print `DoneMsg` and get the second `"Done"`.
You need to add a byte with the value 0 after each of your strings:

```
GenMsg:     db "Generating move list file...",10,0
DoneMsg:    db "Done",10,0
```